# How to sort translucent triangles in OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, translucency

I am writing a 3D game using OpenGL. I have an sorting problem when rendering translucent triangles. I know that they need to be sorted, but how? I don't want to use BSP trees(if I want to change the position of the object then I need to rebuild the tree.) and OIT algorithms(Performance expensive). I want to sort them by "coverage".

I have two translucent triangles and I use perspective camera to project them onto the screen.

Viewport: 0, 0, 1280, 720

**For example**

[CORRECT SORTING] a black triangle covers the green triangle.

[image]

[INCORRECT SORTING] a green triangle covers the black triangle.

[image]

The triangles in the images are opaque in order to clearly see the sorting artifacts.

---

**My solution to this problem**

Transform the vertices of these triangles to screen space coordinates and compare them by interpolating z coordinate, BUT on my images you can see that one coordinate of black triangle is outside the viewport and therefore this coordinate is weird(something like this: -2896; 1423; 1.169) and I cannot interpolate z coordinate on the black triangle.

**How I transform to screen space coordinates**

1. Transform triangle vertices by MVP matrix
2. Perform perspective divide
3. Transform to screen space

Transform by MVP matrix

```
public Vector4f transform(Vector4f vector) {
    float x = m00 * vector.x + m10 * vector.y + m20 * vector.z + m30 * vector.w;
    float y = m01 * vector.x + m11 * vector.y + m21 * vector.z + m31 * vector.w;
    float z = m02 * vector.x + m12 * vector.y + m22 * vector.z + m32 * vector.w;
    float w = m03 * vector.x + m13 * vector.y + m23 * vector.z + m33 * vector.w;

    return new Vector4f(x, y, z, w);
}
```

Perspective divide

```
public Vector3f perspectiveDivide() {
    float wInverse = 1.0f / w;
    return new Vector3f(x * wInverse, y * wInverse, z * wInverse);
}
```

Transform to screen space

```
public void toScreenCoords(int width, int height) {
    x = (x * 0.5f + 0.5f) * width;
    y = (y * 0.5f + 0.5f) * height;
    z = (z + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
}
```

How I perform that

```
Vector4f clipspace = mvp.transform(triangle_vertex);
Vector3f ndc = clipspace.perspectiveDivide();
Vector3f screenspace = ndc.toScreenCoords(1280, 720);
```

---

What I am doing wrong? Why coordinate that outside the viewport is weird? How to get correct coordinate that outside the viewport?

---

--- EDIT ---

I found out that if one coordinate of the triangle outside the viewport then the triangle must be divided into two.

But how to divide the triangle into two using the clip space coordinates and the clipping planes?

Comment: The weird coordinates are probably caused by a vertex that lies behind the camera. Your main problem, however, is that triangles can not always be sorted (imagine three interleaving triangles; in this case, you need to split one of them). Data structures like kd trees or BSP trees allow you to do these splits when necessary. Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: There are a couple of standard clipping algorithms. But I really don't get your approach, especially what does "Transform the vertices of these triangles to screen space coordinates and compare them by interpolating z coordinate." mean? What point(s) do you interpolate the z for?

Comment: @derhass To get points(x, y) for z interpolation, I am looking for the intersection between two lines, one from the first triangle and second from green. Then I interpolate z from the first triangle and the second triangle by this point.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I don't want to use BSP treen because if I want to change the position of the object then I need to rebuild this tree.

Comment: "I am looking for the intersection between two lines, one from the first triangle and second from green. Then I interpolate z from the first triangle and the second triangle by this point." This algorithm does not make the slightest sense. You seem to want to use the 2D projection for these lines, and just do a depth test at one point which is covered by both triangles. But that will only work for cases where the triangles won't intersect - but if that can be assumed, you would not need a complex algorithm for projecting and clipping them first.

Comment: @derhass I assume that triangles will not intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The fast and easy solution to sort (translucent)triangles correctly

"Fake projection sorting" as I call it.
If you can assume that the triangles will not intersect, then you can just check if triangle(black or green) intersects a tetrahedron(coordinates from black of green triangle and camera position).

---

## An example

First triangle coordinates:

```
0.0, 0.0, 5.0
0.0, 5.0, 5.0
5.0, 5.0, 5.0
```

Second triangle coordinates:

```
0.0, 0.0, 5.0
5.0, 0.0, 5.0
5.0, 0.0, 5.0
```

Camera position

```
1.15, 5.8, 5.5
```

Then, tetrahedron coordinates will be coordinates from a triangle(for example, first) and camera position.

```
0.0,  0.0, 5.0  // First coordinate from the first triangle
0.0,  5.0, 5.0  // Second coordinate from the first triangle
5.0,  5.0, 5.0  // Third coordinate from the first triangle
1.15, 5.8, 5.5  // Camera position
```

The last thing you need to do is check if second triangle intersects the tetrahedron. If the **second** triangle intersects, then it covering first triangle. If you use coordinates from the second triangle to create tetrahedron, then you need to check first triangle for intersection instead of second.

---

## Note

Do not use TreeSet or TreeMap from Java to compare triangles using "Fake projection sorting", it can produce incorrect sorting.